# PHP Do-While loop

Tags: php

Below is my unfinished code. The last bit decided to throw a infinite loop. I am trying to create a random number script that will not repeat a number out of the 7 random picks. It seems once I added the `||` on the very last line the script starts to loop. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php 

$n1 = rand(1, 12);
$n2 = rand(13, 21);
$n3 = rand(15, 27);
$n4 = rand(20, 38); 
$n5 = rand(30, 46);
$n6 = rand(39, 49);
$bo = rand(1, 49);

// First number
echo $n1 . " ";

// Second number
do {
    echo $n2 . " ";
} while ($n1 == $n2);

// Third Number
do {
    echo $n3 . " ";
} while ($n3 == $n2 || $n1);

?>
```

Comment: Check out this table for operator precedence : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: I suspect you coded this the way you thought about it, which is to say the final condition (in your mind was): "while n3 equals n2 or n1". In programming logic, you would express this idea as "while n3 equals n2 or n3 equals n1". The way it is currently written the condition evaluates to true if n3 equals n2, or if n1 is not null.

Comment: Brendon i think i was mind stressed when I wrote this. I took a break and  when i came back i saw what i have will not work for what i need it to do. I am going to keep prying at a new method.

I want 7 different numbers between 1 and 49 but each drawn number sits between a specific value or the most drawn values with in a database. this is why the randoms rand() numbers are different.

Comment: I must question why this question was downvoted. Whatever one may think of the quality of the code in it, I don't think there's anything wrong with the quality of the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The priority of || is lower than == so actually it is more like this:

```
while(($n3 == $n2)||$n1))
```

and I think this is not you want so change it to

```
while(($n3 === $n2)||($n3 === $n1))
```

And please keep in mind to use === for comparing.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your help, your solution worked. I have been using == because I thought strings were text wrapped between "

Comment: @KellyDodsworth  How is this correct ? it doesn't solve your looping issues ?

Answer (score 2):

`$n1` is allways different from 0 then

```
do {
    echo $n3 . " ";
} while ($n3 == $n2 || $n1);  //<-- allways true
```

Answer (score 2):

What @Majid said was correct. Check [PHP's operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

The `==` operator precedes `||` operator for execution, so as long as `$n1` is not `false`-y, the loop never exits.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but your last do while loop is configured incorrectly. The below is more correct and wont give you an infinite loop.

```
do {
 $n3 = rand(15, 27);
 echo $n3 . " ";
} while (($n3 == $n2) || ($n3 == $n1));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues here, but here's a start on the right path.  Comments are inline.

```
<?php 

$n1 = rand(1, 12);
$n2 = rand(13, 21);

// First number
echo $n1 . " ";

// Second number
// no loop needed as your rand doesn't overlap your $n1
echo $n2 . " ";

// Third Number
do {
    $n3 = rand(15, 27); // this needs to be in your loop so when its the same it will generate a new number
} while ($n3 == $n2) // your || isn't needed as it can't over lap your $n2

echo $n3 . " ";

// Fourth Number
do {
    $n4 = rand(20, 38); // this needs to be in your loop so when its the same it will generate a new number
} while ($n4 == $n3)

echo $n4 . " ";

// ... repeat 

// Seventh Number
do {
    $bo = rand(1, 49); // this needs to be in your loop so when its the same it will generate a new number
} while ($bo == $n1 || $bo == $n2 || $bo == $n3 || $bo == $n4 || $bo == $n5 || $bo == $n6) // use your || to check against all of your variables

echo $bo;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes - Majid is right, this will most always be an infinite loop.  What you might want is something similar to:

```
$previousNums = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
{
  $try = rand(0, 49);
  while (in_array( $try, $previousNums ) ) {
    // means we have already used this num, so try again
    $try = rand(0, 49);
  } 
  // append this num in the list of previousNums
  $previousNums[] = $try;

  echo ' num = ' . $try;
}
```

Comment: This would work but i am counting numbers.

if $n1 is not equal to $n2 echo $1
but if $n1 does equal $n2 rerun rand(13,21) until $n2 does not equal $n1 then print it.

on top the numbers are not to be just between 1 and 49
1st number is picked between 1 and 12, second between 13 and 21.